# Случайные числа

Tags: java

Как на языке Java получить случайное число?

Comment: и у кого только рука поднялась вопрос заминусовать? По 1000 просмотров в год! Почти по 3 просмотра в день!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;

// Инициализируем генератор
Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
// Получаем случайное число в диапазоне от min до max (включительно)
int number = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1);
```

Функция `rnd.nextInt(limit)` возвращает число от нуля (включительно) до `limit` (не включая `limit`).

Comment: А зачем abs? Его можно просто убрать и всё будет ок и работать будет даже с отрицательными min и max

Comment: @cy6erGn0m остатки непонятных мыслей :).

Answer (score 9):

**Вариант 1:**

Более сложный и более функциональный. Возвращает случайное число от 0 до того что указано в скобках (не включая). Тип возвращаемого числа зависит от использованного метода - *nextInt*, *nextDouble*, *nextFloat* и пр.

```
Random random = new Random();
int num = random.nextInt(100);
```

Если нужен какой-то конкретный промежуток чисел, то делаем так.

```
Random random = new Random();
int num = 36 + random.nextInt(100 - 36);
```

Вернет случайное целое число от 36 до 99.

**Вариант 2:**

Простой, но менее функциональный. Возвращает случайное число типа *double* от 0 до 1.

```
double num = Math.random();
```

Comment: никак не могу понять как вы получили промежуток от 36 до 99, я не умею пользоваться этой функцией

Comment: @icedev-sk, функция `random.nextInt(x)` генерирует случайное число от 0 до x-1, вот собственно и все. Если нужно получить от 36, делаем поправку на это, прибавляя 36 к результату и вычитая 36 из возможного максимума.